# How to test Axios.all and Axios.spread with Jest in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, axios

I am going to write JEST test cases for below method

```
const ApiSearchAddressCodeAndPostalCode = store => next => action => {
    const {
        type,
        txtAdd,
        sortAddressCode
    } = action;

    // Param Of Api Postal Code Search
    const requestBodyPostalCode = {
        postalCode: postalCode,
    };

    const headersPostalCode = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'x-api': apiKey
    };

    return Axios.all([
        Axios.get(
            `${SEARCH_BASE_ADD_URL}/${txtAdd}`,
            { headers: { 'x-api': apiKey } },
            {
                params: {
                    sort: sortAddressCode,
                }
            }
        ),
        //API SEARCH POSTAL CODE - (POST)
        Axios.post(
            SEARCH_BASE_POSTAL_NAME_URL,
            requestBodyPostalCode,
            { headers: headersPostalCode }
        )
    ])
    .then(
        Axios.spread(function(addressCode, postalCode) {
     　     data.resultItem = addressCode.data.resultItem.concat(
               postalCode.data.resultItem
           );
        }
```

It uses axios.all and axios.spread to get the data back..i have written simple test cases for Axios.get and Axios.post. But how to write test case for this?

I tried to write as below.

```
it('Check handle call api success', async () => {
    const mockAxiosSpreadResult = jest.fn();
    axios.all.mockResolvedValue("test");
    axios.spread.mockReturnValue(mockAxiosSpreadResult);
    await ApiSearchAddressCodeAndPostalCode(store)(next)(action);
    expect(mockAxiosSpreadResult).toHaveBeenCalledWith("test");
}
```

Comment: You can count on that axios has it's own tests to check whether this functionality runs as intended. When writing a test you should write it for your own, not for a third party library :)

Comment: Can you make your code syntax correctly?

Comment: @slideshowp2 yes i did

Comment: What are you trying to test exactly? Can you complete the code after the spread? Also, can you provide the missing code for the test (how are you mocking axios)?